# Uniqueness existence of solutions local analytical for a PDE

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider the problem 
$$\begin{cases}u_{tt}=u_{xx}-2au_{x}+a^{2}u, (x,t)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\\[8pt]
u(x,0)=f(x), x\in\mathbb{R}\\[8pt]
u_{t}(x,0)=g(x), x\in\mathbb{R}
\end{cases}$$ 
where $a>0$.

(a)Study the existence and uniqueness of local solutions analytical of the problem, assuming $f$ and $g$ analytic in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$.

(b)Assuming $f\in C^{2}(\mathbb{R}), g\in C^{1}(\mathbb{R})$, show that there exists a unique solution of the problem in $C^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ and display such solution.

Comment: I see this is your seventh question here and yet you've accepted only one answer so far. If you get a satisfying answer, please accept your favorite one.

Comment: What's wrong with my question? Why did I receive $-1$?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, it was someone else.

Comment: I did not downvote either but I can see NO personal thought or comment in this question. This is bad practice since (1) it makes difficult to adjust an answer suited to the level of your understanding, and (2) one could imagine that you are simply dumping your homework on the site and waiting for a full proof to appear to put your name on it and hand it back.

Comment: Who gives downvote in question could say why, can help the questioner! Simply give downvote, can take on all questions.

Comment: @GitGud you could see that I gave answers that were ignored (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261574/a-particular-way-of-write-a-polynomial/261851#261851 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257116/pullback-of-1-form/257137#257137;. Then you also manifest on them!

Comment: @Did, have you seen my questions here on the site? In most, there are my comments. So please, do not talk without knowing.This answers (1). For (2), have you ever thought that most of the issues here can interpretadas so, but not necessarily.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am afraid that the way you asked your other questions is off-topic, hence (1) and (2) fully apply. The last sentence of your comment is not very clear but if you mean that many questions on the site are poorly asked, I agree. If you mean that (1) and (2) apply to most questions on the site, I disagree. Many questions are following the advice given about how to ask. Unfortunately, yours does not, but nothing prevents you to remedy to this NOW on THIS question.

Comment: OK, now I checked: NONE of your questions on the site has ANY personal input.